# Angular2 Project npm start issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I am trying to run my Angular2 app but When I ran command 'npm start' it showed me below errors:

```
Abdul Ovais@DESKTOP-31UBAGF /xampp/htdocs/angular-client
$ npm start

> EES@1.0.0 start D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client
> npm run server:dev


> EES@1.0.0 server:dev D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client
> webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/

'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "server:dev"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! EES@1.0.0 server:dev: `webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the EES@1.0.0 server:dev script 'webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the EES package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs EES
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls EES
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! EES@1.0.0 start: `npm run server:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the EES@1.0.0 start script 'npm run server:dev'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the EES package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run server:dev
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs EES
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls EES
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client\npm-debug.log
```

so I have installed `webpack-dev-server` package and ran command `npm start`, now it showed me below error:

```
Abdul Ovais@DESKTOP-31UBAGF /xampp/htdocs/angular-client
$ npm start

> EES@1.0.0 start D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client
> npm run server:dev


> EES@1.0.0 server:dev D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client
> webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/

Error: Cannot find module './system/supports-colors'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\node_modules\colors\lib\colors.js:39:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\node_modules\colors\safe.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\instance.ts:9:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "server:dev"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! EES@1.0.0 server:dev: `webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the EES@1.0.0 server:dev script 'webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the EES package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs EES
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls EES
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! EES@1.0.0 start: `npm run server:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the EES@1.0.0 start script 'npm run server:dev'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the EES package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run server:dev
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs EES
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls EES
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\xampp\htdocs\angular-client\npm-debug.log
```

*Can anyone help me out!*

Comment: Have you run `npm install`? Looks like you've got missing dependencies. Namely `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: yes I had run command `npm install` and also installed `webpack-dev-server` but right now If I ran `npm start`, it showed me this:

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module './system/supports-colors'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\ees-angular-client\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\node_modules\colors\lib\colors.js:39:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
`

Comment: Try to install `awesome-typ‌​escript-loader` once again. Dependencies of `awesome-typ‌​escript-loader` seems to be broken